# How to parse an int from a string? (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My input looks something like this. Say I'm trying to pull two numbers after a bunch of lines of text that are printed out.

```
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
123 456
```

here is the pseudo code from what I'm trying to use.

```
input.useDelimiter(" "); //I've tried a lot of patterns to no avail.
while(!input.hasNextInt()){
    System.out.println(input.next());
}
System.out.println("Found Ints");
int posRow = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("posRow: "+posRow);
int posCol = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("posCol: "+posCol);
```

my output ends up as

```
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
123
Found Ints
posRow: 456
NoSuchElementException
```

So I'm assuming the issue is that it's reading the last line of text and the first number as one chunk and not an int since there isn't a space. I've tried using \r \n \r\n among others and can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: specify the language (java, c++, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `hasNextLine()` instead of `hasNextInt`, and provided that the number is always the last line, you can split it separately.

How about this?

```
input.useDelimiter(" ");
while(input.hasNextLine()){
    System.out.println(input.nextLine())
}
System.out.println("Found Ints");
int posRow = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("posRow: "+posRow);
int posCol = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("posCol: "+posCol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
input.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\s|\\n"));
```

This will use a space or a new line as the delimiter.

The issue is that using the space for the delimiter causes all the first lines, to the space between the numbers to be one item that is evaluated. This is not an int. Then the next one is, but then there is no more for your final nextInt, hence the exception.